# Why am I getting dark black photos in P, S, and A mode on Nikon D5200?

Tags: nikon, program-mode

I usually shoot in auto mode but I wanted to try the other modes.  In P, M, and A modes, my photos are black.  When I put those photos into an editing program, I can see a very dark picture after I lighten it.

I have reset to default settings and even in bright light, the photos are black/dark in those modes.

Comment: what are the parameters of these pictures (time, aperture, iso)? do you have a negative EV set?

Comment: To expand on what ths said - please post some sample photos, along with the shooting parameters used for each of them. Also, what are you meaning by "bright light"?

Comment: I tried to upload a photo but an error occurred.  I will try again.  I should have said morning sunshine instead of bright light.  The photo that I am trying to upload was taken in P mode and I didn't adjust anything.

Comment: I just uploaded two pictures to my flickr account.  The dark one was taken in P mode and the House Finch was taken in auto mode after the dark photo.  https://www.flickr.com/photos/95380348@N04/with/15938287884

Answer (score 12):

Your correct image shows: ƒ/5.6, 1/500, ISO 800.

Your underexposed image shows: ƒ/9.0, 1/4000, ISO 400.

Your EXIF data shows a **-5 EV Exposure Bias** which seems to be correct, looking at your photos. This is most probably coming from the *exposure compensation* you applied (using the +- icon). All the other settings look okay.

Exposure compensation might stay unaltered if you do not do the proper reset procedure.

Check [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l027ghjlPa4) or your [User Manual](https://cdn-1.nikon-cdn.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5200RM_EN.pdf) out for further info.

(Please let us know if this was the reason.)

Comment: Oh my gosh!  Thank you!  Thank you!  Thank you!  I guess I don't know as much about my camera as I thought I did.  I set the exposure compensation to 0 and it worked in all modes.  Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Very cool! :-) :-)

Comment: @Sue: Click on the check-mark near the answer to make this an accepted answer, and give TFuto a little bonus rep points for identifying the problem.